# How to use NOT BETWEEN SQL with magento collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, collection-filtering

Here is my sql query

```
select * from my_table where status = 1 and CURDATE() NOT BETWEEN start_date and end_date
```

I tried the following code but it is giving me wrong answer when both dates are NULL or any of them. I want to compare the date if it is available.

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
Mage::getModel('mymodule/module')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFilter('status',1)
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                array('start_date', 'end_date'),
                array(
                    array('gt' => $currentDate),
                    array('lt' => $currentDate),

                )
            );
```

Answer (score 3):

**The original answer is for `BETWEEN`. For `NOT BETWEEN` see update below**

For the collection filter operators, it's always useful to take a look at `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::prepareSqlCondition()` which is well documented:

```
/**
 * Build SQL statement for condition
 *
 * If $condition integer or string - exact value will be filtered ('eq' condition)
 *
 * If $condition is array is - one of the following structures is expected:
 * - array("from" => $fromValue, "to" => $toValue)
 * - array("eq" => $equalValue)
 * - array("neq" => $notEqualValue)
 * - array("like" => $likeValue)
 * - array("in" => array($inValues))
 * - array("nin" => array($notInValues))
 * - array("notnull" => $valueIsNotNull)
 * - array("null" => $valueIsNull)
 * - array("gt" => $greaterValue)
 * - array("lt" => $lessValue)
 * - array("gteq" => $greaterOrEqualValue)
 * - array("lteq" => $lessOrEqualValue)
 * - array("finset" => $valueInSet)
 * - array("regexp" => $regularExpression)
 * - array("seq" => $stringValue)
 * - array("sneq" => $stringValue)
 *
 * If non matched - sequential array is expected and OR conditions
 * will be built using above mentioned structure
 *
 * @param string|array $fieldName
 * @param integer|string|array $condition
 * @return string
 */
```

Unfortunately there is no operator for `BETWEEN`, so you will have to either use `$collection->getSelect()` to manipulate the query directly or use a combination of `<` and `>` instead, which can be built using the `from` and `to` keys. For date comparison, there is even an additional `date` or `datetime` key that will make sure that the `from` and `to` parameters are formatted as dates<sup>1</sup>.

But in your case, not the field itself should be "between" to parameters but the current date between two fields, so we cannot use `from`, `to` and `datetime`. Instead we call `addFieldToFilter()` twice so that the conditions are combined with `AND`:

```
->addFieldToFilter(array('start_date' => array('lt' => $curDate))
->addFieldToFilter(array('end_date' => array('gt' => $curDate));
```

To really use `CURDATE()` from MySQL and avoid trouble from timezone settings in PHP, initialize `$curDate` like this:

```
$curDate = new Zend_Db_Expr('CURDATE()');
```

**Update:**

Since you were asking for `NOT BETWEEN`, you need to switch `lt` and `gt` and add both conditions in a single `addFieldToFilter` call to combine them with `OR`:

```
->addFieldToFilter(array(
    'start_date' => array('gt' => $curDate),
    'end_date' => array('lt' => $curDate)
));
```

This will also find records where `start_date` is `NULL` and `end_date` is in the past (and vice versa), but not records where `start_date` and `end_date` are both `NULL`. This makes sense if `start_date` and `end_date` follow the same semantics as in core Magento and you want to find all records that are currently not within the range.

So you already were close to the solution but passed the parameters in a wrong form.

---

<sup>1) In theory, `'date' => true` should format the parameter as date and `'datetime' => true` as date and time. But they forgot to pass the `$includeTime` parameter to `formatDate()` in `_prepareSqlDateCondition()`, so they both use the default format (date and time)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. I think we can only use OR to achieve the expected result
`->addFieldToFilter(
                    array('start_date', 'end_date'),
                    array(
                        array('gt' => $currentDate),
                        array('lt' => $currentDate),

                    )
                );`

But the above filter does not consider the records that have NULL value of start_date or end_date column.

I want those record as well.

Comment: Please see update